# Does the set of Continuous functions always separate points and vanish nowhere?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be an arbitrary metric space. Does $C(X;\mathbb{R})$ always separate points and vanish nowhere?

I think this is true because the functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1$ are both in $C(X;\mathbb{R})$ and separate points and does not vanish.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is not an element of $C(X;\mathbb R)$ for a general metric space $X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I now understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these two functions do suffice to show that for $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Or use $f$ and $g(x)=x+1$, as $f$ and $g$ never simultaneously are $0$. But the definition of $f$ assumes all points of $X$ are reals.

For general metric $X$ consider using $f_p(x) = d(x,p)$ for $p \in X$ as continuous functions, and also $g$.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on your last statement for a general metric?

Comment: @MatteoLepur If $x \neq y$, what are $f_x(x)$ and $f_x(y)$?

Comment: $f_x(x) = 0$ and $f_x(y)$ $\not=$ $0$. I don't see how this helps us. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @hennobrandsma you're saying since there are at least two different points in the metric space then $ f_p(x)= d(x,y) $ is not equal to zero for some x in X, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @KaanYolsever If we have at least two points we can separate them by some $f_x$ and the constant function always shows non-vanishingness.

Comment: @MatteoLepur The definition of separating points, is that for $x \neq y$ some $f$ has $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Comment: @MatteoLepur The fucntions $f_p$ I defined  are just some of the continuous functions on $X$ but they suffice to show that the real-valued continuous functions separate points.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you very much. Perfect.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sorry for bothering but why are metrics continuous in every metric space

Comment: @KaanYolsever search for “metric continuous” on this site. Plenty of answers. But basically the triangle inequality implies $|f_p(x) - f_p(y) \le d(x,y)$ which implies continuity right away.